# RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered in Colab GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train Fast R-CNN model.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
   train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
   lr_scheduler.step()
   evaluate(model, test_data_loader, device=device)
```

I got an error message like below:

```
Epoch: [0]  [ 0/44]  eta: 0:06:57  lr: 0.000121  loss: 4.3884 (4.3884)  loss_classifier: 2.2335 (2.2335)  loss_box_reg: 0.5938 (0.5938)  loss_objectness: 1.1169 (1.1169)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.4442 (0.4442)  time: 9.4806  data: 0.0647  max mem: 8185 

Epoch: [0]  [10/44]  eta: 0:01:23  lr: 0.001283  loss: 3.0393 (3.2865)  loss_classifier: 1.6433 (1.5846)  loss_box_reg: 0.6233 (0.6344)  loss_objectness: 0.4546 (0.6190)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.4568 (0.4485)  time: 2.4648  data: 0.0562  max mem: 8452
Epoch: [0]  [20/44]  eta: 0:00:51  lr: 0.002444  loss: 2.3247 (2.7535)  loss_classifier: 0.9013 (1.2215)  loss_box_reg: 0.6103 (0.6059)  loss_objectness: 0.3435 (0.4777)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.4568 (0.4484)  time: 1.7700  data: 0.0529  max mem: 8452
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-f72d124a6bf2> in <module>
      2 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
----> 3     train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, train_data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
      4     lr_scheduler.step()
...

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/models/detection/roi_heads.py in fastrcnn_loss(class_logits, box_regression, labels, regression_targets)
     34     # the corresponding ground truth labels, to be used with
     35     # advanced indexing
---> 36     sampled_pos_inds_subset = torch.where(labels > 0)[0]
     37     labels_pos = labels[sampled_pos_inds_subset]
     38     N, num_classes = class_logits.shape

RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

After getting this error I cannot even use manuel_seed function.

```
torch.manual_seed(1)
```

I got this error again:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```